# How best to deal with OAuth2 authorisation code grant needing user info with node-oauth2-server?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

**O.K this is driving me crazy**

I am using [this node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-oauth-server) 
to perform oauth authorization. I can get the password grant working since it involves just sending the right headers to the token endpoint. Nice and simple.

Now I want to authorize using the authorization_code grant. However, I need an access token or session to determine what user I am. [This issue](https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server/issues/314) talks about how to do that.

I am still a bit unsure about a few things after reading the issue:

- Should I get the initial user token from password grant?
- Should I have access tokens to signin users and access tokens to sign
  clients?

  - One has only user info the other has user and client info.
- OR, Should I implement a users session in my oauth server?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: is it **your** authentication server? if so, why do you need an authorization flow (used to allow 3rd party apps to access user data)

Comment: We provide a bunch of services within a VPC which clients will have to access. The authorization_code grant seems to be the type I need but I don't understand how I should implement the user login. The issue above showed session data or tokens to sign in but that doesn't seem right. Do I keep a store of token for clients access to resources AND users signed in? I suppose I should but what is the best way to implement that with the module above. Thanks for the help.